# Multiple value in Query Builder in a Python Script

Tags: arcpy, sql, query

I want to do a multiple value selection in this query with an parameter input.
The parameter Regiao_Estado gets a value like the example: [AC, DF] put in the line from the script:

```
lyr.definitionQuery = 'UF IN' '('Regiao_Estado')'
```

the whole code is here. The parameter Tabela1 only exists to get the value for the field Ano.
The script will do a query to select values and after that get the sum of the field. For one value it`s ok, But I want for multiple values and maybe multiple fields selection.

```
Layer1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Tabela1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
Regiao_Estado = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
Ano = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) 
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")  

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):  
    lyr.name = Layer1
    lyr.definitionQuery = 'UF IN' Regiao_Estado
    arcpy.Statistics_analysis(Layer1, "F:\AgroBD.gdb\Output1", [[Ano, "SUM"]], "")
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (M6a.py, line 10)
Failed to execute (Consulta).
```

I tried many ways to solve this problem but don`t get any progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You havent created the SQL query properly.

Try:

```
lyr.definitionQuery = """UF IN ({})""".format(Regiao_Estado)
```

EDIT:

If you need to expand the query, try the below. This using python string formatting. Please see this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) for more info.

```
lyr.definitionQuery = """UF IN ({0}) OR UF IN ({1})""".format(Regiao_Estado, Test)
```

Comment: Macro, It`s work well, But I need to remove the two single ('). I can use this format with two fields too? Like UF and another ''TEST' field with another values.

Comment: This definition query will select multiple attributes in the UF field. If you need to select from a different field, you need to change the definition query and add an "OR" operator. for example UF IN (...) OR UF IN (...).

Comment: Nice, but I can use the same format? see the example: """UF IN ({})""".format(Regiao_Estado) AND """UF IN ({})""".format(TEST)

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: MacroZED, another question. Do you see any possible to do a multivalue selection in arcpy.Statistics_analysis(Layer1, "F:\AgroBD.gdb\Output1", [[Ano, "SUM"]], "")? I will choose more than one field to calculate, But I get an error, even using arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3).split(";") for the parameter.